# Laravel Changing number to Text

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Working on a Laravel 4.2 app here, I have a SQL value in which it returns a 0 or 1 value. I would like to cast this as a Yes/No field, how would I do this in my coding? On the Controller side of things I assume?

Blade PHP:

```
  <td>{{  $value->allow_na  }}</td>
```

Controller:

```
$value->allow_na = Input::get('allow_na');
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Blade you can do

```
<td>{{  ($value->allow_na)?'Yes':'No'  }}</td>
```

Or Same way on controller

```
$value->allow_na = (Input::get('allow_na'))?'Yes':'No';
```

Comment: which is better, in the controller or in the blade in your opinion?

Comment: Depends upon your need to manipulate and reuse of that data. I have often used it on view coz i need that 0/1 for other purposes.And checking for it on other places on view is easy.

Answer (score 0):

Another option, on your model you can add a mutator to convert that for you every time.

```
public function setAllowNAAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['allow_na'] = ($value) ? 'Yes' : 'No';
}
```

Link : https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators

Answer (score 0):

Blade PHP:

```
<td>{{  $value->allow_na  }}</td>
```

Controller:

```
if ( Input::get('allow_na') == 0 )
   { 
       $value->allow_na = "No";
   }
else
   { 
       $value->allow_na = "Yes";
   }
```